# How to optmize query with a query with multiple GROUP BY's,sub queries and WHERE IN over a large table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, query-optimization

I am working on a scraping project to crawl items and their scores over different schedules.Schedule is a user defined period (date) when the script is intended to run.

Table structure is as follows:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `test_join`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_join` (
  `schedule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('celebrity','sportsperson') NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schedule_id`,`player_name`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test_join`
--

INSERT INTO `test_join` (`schedule_id`, `player_name`, `type`, `score`) VALUES
(1, 'sachin', 'sportsperson', 100),
(1, 'ganguly', 'sportsperson', 80),
(1, 'dravid', 'sportsperson', 60),
(1, 'sachin', 'celebrity', 100),
(2, 'sachin', 'sportsperson', 120),
(2, 'ganguly', 'sportsperson', 100),
(2, 'sachin', 'celebrity', 120);
```

The scraping is done over periods and for each schedule it is expected to have about 10k+ entries.The schedules could be made in daily basis,hence the data would grow to be be around 2 million in 5-6 months.

Over this data I need to perform queries to aggregate the player who come across each schedules in a selected range of schedules.

For example:

I need aggregate same players who come across multiple schedules. If schedule 1 and 2 are selected,items which come under both of the schedules only will be selected.

I am using the following query to aggregate results based on the type,

For schedule 1:

```
SELECT fullt.type,COUNT(*) as count,SUM(fullt.score) FROM
(SELECT tj.*
FROM `test_join` tj
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT `player_name`,`type`,COUNT(`schedule_id`) as c FROM `test_join` WHERE `schedule_id` IN (1,2) GROUP BY `player_name`,`type` HAVING c=2) stj 
on tj.player_name = stj.player_name 
WHERE tj.`schedule_id`=1
GROUP BY tj.`type`,tj.`player_name`)AS fullt
GROUP BY fullt.type
```

**Reason for c = 2;**

```
WHERE `schedule_id` IN (1,2) GROUP BY `player_name`,`type` HAVING c=2
```

*Here we are selecting two schedules,1 and 2.Hence the count 2 is taken to make the query to to fetch records which belongs to both the schedules and occurs twice.*

It would generate a results as follows,

**Schedule 1 :Expected Results**

[image: Schedule 1 :Expected Results]

**Schedule 2 :Expected Results**

[image: Schedule 2 :Expected Results]

This is my expected result and the query returns the results as above.
(In the real case I have to work across pretty big MySQL tables)

On my understanding of standardized MySQL queries, using sub queries,WHERE IN, varchar comparison fields ,multiple GROUP BY's would affect in the query performance.
I need the aggregate results in real time and query speed and well as standards are a concern too.How this could be optimized for better performance in this context.

EDIT:

I had reduced sub queries now:

```
SELECT fullt.type,COUNT(*) as count,SUM(fullt.score) FROM (
SELECT t.*
FROM `test_join` t 
INNER JOIN test_join t1 ON t.`player_name` = t1.player_name AND t1.schedule_id = 1
INNER JOIN test_join t2 ON t.player_name = t2.player_name AND t2.schedule_id = 2
WHERE t.schedule_id = 2 
GROUP BY t.`player_name`,t.`type`) AS fullt
GROUP BY fullt.type
```

Is this a better way to do so.I had replaced WHERE IN with JOINS.

Any advise would be highly appreciated.I would be happy to provide any supporting information if needed.

Comment: Your example structure, data and results are ok, however, WHAT is it you are actually trying to do.  What is  the real purpose of the query (context, not just get count and sum).  If dealing with large numbers, it might be better to have a pre-aggregate table already done and query from that vs plowing through millions of records.

Comment: @DRapp the real purpose of the query is to get the aggregate details in real time.I will select a range of schedules,say schedule 1,2 and 3; and I should get those players who belong to all the three schedules and their count and sum of scores by type for each schedules.

I'm not clear about per-aggregate tables,here in my case the user is to select various schedules randomly and results should be populated accordingly. I understood there are certain limitations in plowing through whole set of records,but I would like to know how this could be don in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

**try below SQL Query in MYSQL:**

```html
SELECT tj.`type`,COUNT(*) as count,SUM(tj.`score`) FROM
`test_join` tj
where tj.`schedule_id`=1 
and `player_name` in 
(
select tj1.`player_name` from `test_join` tj1 
group by tj1.`player_name` having count(tj1.`player_name`) > 1  
)
group by tj.`type`
```

**Actuallly I tried same data in Sybase as i dont have MySQL installed in my machine.It worked as exepected !**

```html
CREATE TABLE #test_join
 (
  schedule_id int NOT NULL,
  player_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  type1 varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  score int NOT NULL,
 ) 

INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES
(1, 'sachin', 'sportsperson', 100)



INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES(1, 'ganguly', 'sportsperson', 80)
INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES(1, 'dravid', 'sportsperson', 60)
INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES(1, 'sachin', 'celebrity', 100)
INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES(2, 'sachin', 'sportsperson', 120)
INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES(2, 'ganguly', 'sportsperson', 100)
INSERT INTO #test_join (schedule_id, player_name, type1, score) VALUES(2, 'sachin', 'celebrity', 120)

select * from #test_join


Print 'Solution #1 : Inner join'

select type1,count(*),sum(score) from 
#test_join
where schedule_id=1 and player_name in (select player_name from #test_join t1 group by player_name having count(player_name) > 1  )
group by type1



select player_name,type1,sum(score) Score into #test_join_temp 
from #test_join 
group by player_name,type1
having count(player_name) > 1

Print 'Solution #2 using Temp Table'
--select * from #test_join_temp 
select type1,count(*),sum(score) from 
#test_join
where schedule_id=1 and player_name in (select player_name from #test_join_temp )
group by type1
```

I hope This Helps :)

Comment: //select tj1.`player_name` from `test_join` tj1 
group by tj1.`player_name` having count(tj1.`player_name`) > 1  //

Why did you use - **having count(tj1.`player_name`) > 1** , where did 1 came from.What should be done when i have to select through n schedules ?

Also ,do you think it would be a good attempt gaining performance?

Comment: Count > 1 will decide, players who are part of multiple schedule. Performance would be surely better than your query. As you have real data you can verify the time for each schedule and decide. Thanks.

Comment: //Count > 1 will decide, players who are part of multiple schedule.// In the real case I'm having lot of schedules, for eg: If a user select 1,3,5,7,9,10 schedules. How will the results come according to your query? In my case:in a situation nas above; The subquery would be as follows: (SELECT player_name,type,COUNT(schedule_id) as c FROM test_join WHERE schedule_id IN (1,3,5,7,9,10) GROUP BY player_name,type HAVING c=6)